# backup and restore permissions

Tags: powershell, acl, directory

I am currently using the following script to export the permissions, take ownership of a folder and then remove all permissions from that folder. The folder list is taken from a text file.

```
$InputFile = "C:\temp\Folders.txt"
$OutputFile = "C:\temp\FolderPermissions.txt"
$FolderList = Get-Content $InputFile

foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    Get-Acl $folder | Format-List >>$OutputFile

    $acl = Get-ACL -Path $folder
    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($True, $True)
    Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl

    $ACL = Get-ACL -Path $Folder
    $Rules = $ACL.Access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -notmatch 'Admin'}

    foreach ($Rule in $Rules) {
        [void]$ACL.RemoveAccessRule($Rule)
    }
    Set-Acl -Path $folder -AclObject $acl
}
```

I really want to be able to reverse this, but cannot figure out how to reapply the permissions from the file that it exports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List format is okay for human readers, but it's not really suitable for restoring data from a file. Save the full path and [SDDL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379567.aspx) of each folder to a CSV:

```
foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    Get-Acl $folder | Select-Object @{n='Path';e={$Folder.FullName}}, Sddl |
        Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoType -Append
    ...
}
```

That should allow you to restore the security information like [this](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/replacing-ntfs-permissions-with-sddl-information):

```
Import-Csv $OutputFile | ForEach-Object {
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.Path
    $acl.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm($_.Sddl)
    Set-Acl -Path $_.Path -AclObject $acl
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ive tried this but it only seems to process the first line in the txt file. Any ideas?

Comment: @david You need to append to the output file (requires PowerShell v3), otherwise the file will only contain the data of the last folder. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Does the txt need to be in any specific format

Comment: This works mate, brilliant. Thanks for your help. Do you know how i could make it output to a separate file for any folders it cannot access?.